# "it is" vs "it can be"

Tags: word-choice

I am proofreading this text and I am tempted to replace *is* with *can be* to make it more interesting and dynamic to the reader.

> The attitude of his employer is always correct, but ***it is crushing*** to the others.

Is the following sentence milder?

> The attitude of his employer is always correct, but ***it can be crushing*** to the others.

While I was replacing *is* with *can be*, it struck me that often when we say that *something ***can be*** interesting* we simply mean that ***it is** interesting*.

Comment: I know this difference, but I was wondering if they could be used interchangeably as a matter of style, not of meaning.

Comment: That's because you do not understand my intuition. I am not concerned with meaning here, but with style. I see contexts where both can be used, but _**can be**_ sounds more elegant without much difference in actual meaning. But I may be splitting hairs... I like that! :)

Comment: See @LawrenceC's answer. He understood what I meant. I think I will accept his answer, since it is the closest to the confirmation I was looking for. I agree with what he says, although I wouldn't call this use wrong.

Comment: Ok, that's your opinion and I respect it. But I would appreciate it if you did not impose it on me.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not necessarily that.

**'is'** would depict it is always present. No matter his attitude, it always feels like crushing others.

**'can be'** would depict possibility. It roots its usage from the modal verb **can**.

Comment: [like he is crushing others.]

Answer (score 1):

> it struck me that often when we say that something can be interesting we simply mean that it is interesting.

You can't take modals at "face value" in English all the time.

Modals are often "misused" by the speaker/writer for politeness, often in a professional, business, or legal setting.  Things possibly "hidden" by modals are:

- harsh statements
- imperatives by those in authority
- concessions, deferences, or refusals to those in authority
- the speaker/writer doesn't want to make it seem like what he/she says will definitely happen or is always true

> The attitude of his employer is always correct, but it can be crushing to the others

So yes, the speaker here might be trying to make it milder, or the speaker might be trying to give the impression that the attitude of his employer *isn't always* crushing.

Then of course the speaker might mean it literally--simply that the employer's attitude is able to be crushing to others.